# foreach in powershell to retrieve processes

Tags: powershell

The output of processes does not show in the results. I'm logging into each server and pulling the processes. If I do just one server without the foreach it outputs the processes, however  when I add a for each with a list of servers, it doesn't show the results

```
$serverListFile = "servers.csv"
$global:ServerLists = Import-Csv -Path $global:ScriptPath\$ServerListFile -Delimiter "," | ForEach-Object  {
    $_.servers

    $currentServer = $_.servers
    Write-Host $currentServer

    Write-Host "Getting first 5 Processes on" $currentServer

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_.servers -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {
        Get-Process | Select-Object -First 5
    }
}
```

Here are the results:

```
Server1
Getting first 5 Processes on Server1
Server2
Getting first 5 Processes on Server2
Server3
Getting first 5 Processes on Server3
```

Comment: How does the input look? Remember to show some examples, please.

Comment: What is the reason for insisting on the `ForEach-Object`?  The `-ComputerName` parameter will accept an array of computer names and will handle the enumeration for you.  You can supply as many as you like and it will, by default, process them in batches of up to 32 at once - you can adjust that number using the `-ThrottleLimit` parameter.  See the [Invoke-Command help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-5.1) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are saving everything in the loop to a variable the output from the command is just being saved their instead of writing to the console.

You could save the output from the `invoke-command` to a variable and then do a `write-output` and a `write-host`.

```
$proc = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_.servers -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {
    Get-Process | Select-Object -First 5 | Out-String
    } 
    Write-Output $proc
    Write-Host $proc
```

This way it will output to the console and the output will be saved to your  `$global:ServerLists` variable as well.